# ParseException: Unparseable date exception

Tags: java, date, datetime

thanks.

system default locale difference.

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM d, yyyy h:mm:ss a", Locale.ENGLISH);

get solved.

String to Date Error

String : `Feb 13, 2017 10:25:43 AM`

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy h:mm:ss a");
```

or `MMM d, yyyy h:mm:ss a`, `MMM d, yyyy hh:mm:ss a`, `MMM dd, yyyy h:mm:ss a`, `MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm:ss a`, `MMM dd, yyyy H:mm:ss a`, `MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss a`
...etc

> ParseException ::::: Unparseable date: "Feb 13, 2017 10:25:43 AM"

plz help.

Comment: Works as you can see [in live code here at IdeOne.com](http://ideone.com/B9SzGo). Voting to **close this Question as unreproducible**. Though you should be using java.time classes rather than these troublesome old legacy date-time classes.

Comment: No issue here either

Comment: What is the default Locale of your system?

Comment: thanks. system default locale difference. get solved.
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM d, yyyy h:mm:ss a", Locale.ENGLISH);

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDateTime.parse( 
    "Feb 13, 2017 10:25:43 AM" , 
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "MMM d, uuuu hh:mm:ss a" , Locale.US )  
)
```

> 2017-02-13T10:25:43

## java.time

You are using troublesome old date-time classes that are now legacy, supplanted by the *java.time* classes.

Specify a formatting pattern to match your input. Note that we pass a `Locale` to specify the human language and cultural norms used in translating name of month and such.

```
String input = "Feb 13, 2017 10:25:43 AM" ;
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "MMM d, uuuu hh:mm:ss a" , Locale.US ) ;
```

Your input string lacks any indicator of time zone or offset-from-UTC. So parse as a `LocalDateTime`.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( input , f  );
```

> ldt.toString(): 2017-02-13T10:25:43

By the way, if your input had had a comma after the year, you could have parsed using an automatically localized formatter rather than bothering to define a formatting pattern. That comma is apparently the norm for the United States (at least).

```
String input = "Feb 13, 2017, 10:25:43 AM" ;  // With a comma after year, apparently the norm in the United States.
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime( FormatStyle.MEDIUM ).withLocale( Locale.US )
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( input , f  );
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).